# UIPageController and gesture recognizers

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

I am using UIPageController to implement a page based navigation application. I would like to enable the swipe gestures only at the margin of the page and prevent that from the inner content view. The page has a margin of 20 pixels:

```
contentView.frame = CGRectInset(self.view.frame, 20, 20);
```

Answer (score 1):

Upon recognising a gesture you should be able to retrieve the [locationInView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIGestureRecognizer/locationInView%3a) and then if this is an acceptable value proceed, otherwise not.

Answer (score 0):

First add  in the class interface.

```
@interface MyPageViewController :UIViewController<UIPageViewControllerDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
```

Then in viewDidLoad add

```
for (UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer in self.pageViewController.gestureRecognizers) {

        recognizer.delegate = self;

}
```

Then implement shouldReceiveTouch method

```
#pragma mark - UIGestureRecognizer delegate methods
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch{


    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.pageViewController.view];

    CGRect innerRect =  CGRectInset(self.pageViewController.view.frame, 40, 40);

   if (CGRectContainsPoint(innerRect, touchPoint)) {
        return NO;
   }

   return YES;
}
```